# shell script counting semicolons in a string

Tags: shell

I wrote the following code as part of my project work. I need to print `i` value based on the number of `;`(semi colons) in the input string. But the `while` loop is not getting executed. It is returning errors. I tried lot of alternatives but could not figure it out.

```
IN="aa;bb;cc;"
c= echo $IN | tr -dc ';' | wc -c 
echo $c 
i=1
while [ $i -le $c ]; 
do 
    echo $i
    i=`expr $i + 1` 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
c= echo $IN | tr -dc ';' | wc -c
```

to this:

```
c=`echo $IN | tr -dc ';' | wc -c`
```

so that `echo $IN | tr -dc ';' | wc -c` is run, and its output saved in `c` — just like you're already doing for `i` later in the script:

```
i=`expr $i + 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can use  `awk`, it's much shorter and easier:

```
echo $IN | awk '{ print length(gensub("[^;]","","g",$0)) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for looping once you have a string of `;`. The shell can count the characters in a variable for you with `${#variable}`.

```
$ IN="aa;bb;cc;"
$ c=$(echo $IN | tr -dc ';')
$ echo ${#c}
3
```